# Copy a workbook, move all formulas over one column

Tags: worksheet-function

Does anyone know if it is possible to copy a worksheet but move all of the formulas in the new worksheet over one column?  I have a master sheet that holds a lot of data so i want to create WS2 once then copy it over 20 times each time moving out to the next column.